# Angular - Listening for a specific DOM insertion, then listen for scroll event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, typescript2.0

Let's say this is the HTML for a widget element:

```
<div class = "a b">
     <div class = "c d e">
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to listen for that widget being added to the DOM (preferably catch it by html class). And when it is added, I want to listen for a scroll event (mouse-wheel or the drag-down scroller), so that when the user scrolls, the widget is removed from the DOM.

I've heard of various implementations including using `document.queryselector()`, `@HostListener`, Event emitter, `ngDoCheck` etc. I'm looking for  an implementation that has the smallest impact on performance, and preferably all within my angular component, let's call it `MyComponent`.

EDIT: The application I'm working on is a large enterprise application

EDIT 2: I don't have access to the widget's Angular component, that's why I can't use `@ViewChild`, so the only way I can catch it is by it's class names when it's added to the DOM. The widget is displayed after an icon is clicked; I haven't been able to find the icon's onclick event handler either.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what you have tried so far and where are you stuck. Thanks

Comment: I have tried to catch the element using `document.queryselector("div.a.b")`, but I'm worried that it will have a huge impact on the application's performance.

Comment: querySelector should not impact the performance but i will suggest angular implementation within the component.

Comment: could you be a little more specific? Thanks

Comment: how or why is this component added to the page? that detail is fairly important. is there a reason you can't be explicitly notified of it being added? is it added within the component?  This is all pretty important as the "angular" way of doing things usually involves explicit signals

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: like earlier commented, what is this widget, how do you display it? It's an important detail here.

Comment: It's a devexpress widget. When it appears after clicking on an icon, it is inserted into the html's `<body>` tag as a `<div>` element; when you click away from it, it is removed from `<body>`. I want to replicate the effect of removing the widget from the html, but for a scroll event.
I can't find the widget's event handler, that's why I'm doing it the way I described.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with event delegation. Assign the scroll listener to the document, then search and remove your div if it exists.

```js
let new_div = document.createElement('div');
new_div.id = 'your_widget';
new_div.style.height = '5000px';
new_div.innerText = "hello";
document.body.appendChild(new_div);

document.addEventListener('scroll', (e)=>{
    if(document.querySelector('#your_widget')){
        document.querySelector('#your_widget').remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I'm looking for Angular specific code

Comment: One way to do it is to establish listeners for both events, then use a static flag to tell the "scroll" handler that the "add" has happened.